# tikz 3D rotation around an the (x,y) = (1,1) axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating, animations

I would like to do an animation of a 3D axis (x,y,z) that undergoes a 180 degrees rotation around the axis (1,1,0). The result should be the same 3D axis, where x and y are interchanged and z goes to -z.

I can't manage to do that even if I try to reproduce [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257947/tikz-3dplot-rotate-arc-around-specific-axis), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67573/tikz-shift-and-rotate-in-3d) or others

Comment: What have you tried? PGF/Ti*k*Z is not the best choice for 3D, let alone animated 3D, because it doesn't actually know the world has more than 2 dimensions.

Comment: @cfr I have tried to reproduce the solutions given in the links... If you know a better/easier solution, I'm happy

Comment: What exactly have you tried and what is the problem? Which code did you compile exactly and what didn't work? Did you get an error? (Which?) Did you get unexpected output? (What and what did you expect?)

Comment: @cfr I can't do a correct rotation around the desired axis. All I can do i a rotation alors x, y or z.  It is not a compilation problem. I used essentially the http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67588/38928 answer for the rotation. I planned on creating many figures with different angles to create my annimation. But I can't find the correct set of angles for the rotation. The solution given there allows rotation around x,y and z but not around (x,y) = (1,1), I mean a rotation around a diagonal axis in the xy plane. Btw thanks for your help